# Drag/Moving a shape around jPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

Yesterday I ask a question about how to draw a bounding box to hold a shape inside and **how to drag and drop that selected shape**.

The first question is solved. But I'm having some trouble to move the shape. Is there any especific transformations to move a shape around the jPanel?

I have this code:

```
public boolean drag(MouseEvent e) {
    if(points.isEmpty()) //if point's vector is empty
        return false;

    if(!selected)
        return false;

    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getX();

    if (!dragging)
        lastMovePoint.setLocation(x, y);

    dragging = true;

    int deslocX = 0;
    int deslocY = 0;

    int oldX = -1;
    int oldY = -1;

    int size = points.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        oldX = lastMovePoint.x;
        oldY = lastMovePoint.y;

        deslocX = x - oldX;
        deslocY = y - oldY;

        points.set(i, new Point(points.get(i).x + deslocX, points.get(i).y + deslocY));
//set the vector of points so that when there is a repaint() it repaints the shape with the new
//coordinates


    }
     lastMovePoint.setLocation(x, y); //set the location of the old point
    return true;
}
```

This method is called by the listener mouseDragged and return true in case of sucess. What I'm trying to do is to add the difference between the previous point of dragg and the actual.

When I run this code I have a problem:

The shape only goes to right/left, up and down is not working...

.

Comment: Please consider creating and posting your [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a **small** test program that we can compile, test, that demonstrates your problem for us, and that we can try to help you improve. Also why AWT Canvas and not a Swing JPanel?

Comment: Is a JPanel yes. I already edit. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = e.getX(), y = e.getX();
```

This should probably be changed to

```
int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
```

That's why it only works in the x direction, you aren't actually taking into account the Y direction

Comment: Oh! I change, now it works worse... It goes right and left very slow and not in a fluid way.

Comment: If a drag the mouse UP/DOWN the shape goes right/left perfectly, like was supposed to if a drag RIGHT/LEFT.

Comment: Problem solved, some other mistake in my code. Sorry for the waste of time, but I hope this code can help someone else, so I will not delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in order to drag components you also need to know the starting location so you can calculate the distance the mouse has moved.

Here is some code that shows this general behaviour for moving a window.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MoveWindow extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JWindow window = new JWindow();
        window.setSize(300, 300);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        window.setVisible(true);

        MouseInputAdapter listener = new MoveWindow();
        window.addMouseListener( listener );
        window.addMouseMotionListener( listener );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'll let you implement it for your purposes.

Comment: Thank for your perspective. Sometimes the problem is not about programming, is about maths.

Next I have to rotate, resize (like a shape in paint).

My teachers said to use matrix's operations, is that the best way to do?